# Fetching logs from log file using grep

Tags: grep, logs

I am trying to fetch logs from log file using `grep` command and format of log file is as follows:

```
[1/10/16 23:55:33:018 PST] 00000057 ServerObj E   SECJ0373E: Exception message
at com.own.ws.wim.util.UniqueNameHelper.formatUniqueName(UniqueNameHelper.java:102)
at com.own.ws.wim.ProfileManager.getImpl(ProfileManager.java:1569)
```

Until now, I am able to fetch logs but I want stack trace as well.

```
grep -i '^[[:space:]]*at' --before-context=2 SystemOut.log | grep "1/13/16 7:[1-60]" 

output : [1/10/16 23:55:33:018 PST] 00000057 ServerObj E   SECJ0373E: Exception message
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Awk with a field separator of "at" can also work. "^[" matches lines starting with the date stamp and $1 is the first field.

```
awk -F"at" '/^\[/{print $1}' test
```

Based on your comment and if I understand properly what you need, the awk command should include the lines you are looking for with your grep range between 7 and 8 o'clock.

However, it sounds like you need two lists. To do this you could run the awk command on your log file and output it to another file. You could then awk/grep the second file.

```
awk -F"at" '/^\[/{print $1}' test>> ExtractedLogs.txt
awk -F"at" '$1 ~ "07:"{print $1}' ExtractedLogs.txt>> StackTraceOnly.txt
```

Comment: grep "1/13/16 7:[1-60]"  --> This is fetching based on time from 7 to 8 0'clock. So I just want to combine these two filters.

Answer (score 0):

You could add --after-context=2, to add the other lines back in after finding the "at" line:

```
grep -i '^[[:space:]]*at' --before-context=2 afile | grep --after-context=2 "1/13/16 7:[1-60]"
```